# DRF - How to create a ListSerializer from an array of serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that I am populating using a function. 
So I am stacking a list of this particular serializer on an array.

How do I transform this array of serializer into a ListSerializer per say?

Here is my code:

`serializers.py`

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = (
            'name',
)

class ErrorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        error = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
        class Meta:
        fields=(
            'error',
            )

class EqSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    course = CourseSerializer(many=False)
    error = ErrorSerializer(many=False)
```

`api.py`

```
 ...
for c in serializer.validated_data:
            course = models.Course.objects.filter(id=1)#simplifying 
            if len(course)==0:
                error="No Courses Found"
            elif len(course)>1:
                error="Too many courses"
            else:
                x = serializers.CourseSerializer(course[0])
                e = serializers.ErrorSerializer(data={'error':'none'} )
                e.is_valid()
                equate = serializers.EqSerializer(data={'course':x.data,'error':e.data})
                ferr.append(equate) #ferr is my array of  EqSerializer
        resp = serializers.EqSerializer(data=ferr,many=True)#problem is here
```

How do I make this `ferr` into a `serializers.EqSerializer` list

Comment: Can you explain the currently facing problem?

Comment: @JPG when I try to convert the `ferr` to the ListSerializer, it fails when I try to send a `resp.data` reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same issue, here is the solution, just create an array of the dictionaries that generate the ListSerializer and it should work

```
for c in serializer.validated_data:
            course = models.Course.objects.filter(id=1)#simplifying 
            if len(course)==0:
                error="No Courses Found"
            elif len(course)>1:
                error="Too many courses"
            else:
                x = serializers.CourseSerializer(course[0])
                e = serializers.ErrorSerializer(data={'error':'none'} )
                e.is_valid()

                ferr.append({'course':x.data,'error':e.data}) 
resp = serializers.EqSerializer(data=ferr,many=True)
```